# Android Studio, okhttp: Building a Release version of app causes NullPointerException: getConnectionId(...)

Tags: kotlin, signalr, okhttp, proguard, android-r8

Building a release version of app and running it, causes following error:
When building a debug version, the app works as expected.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: e9.s Dispatcher
Process: com.example.premi, PID: 18240
java.lang.NullPointerException: getConnectionId(...) must not be null
at y4.c.a(SourceFile:392)
at y4.i$b.d(SourceFile:87)
at i9.e$a.run(SourceFile:43)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

I am using Okhttp client that throws Callback failure  with code 400 just before Fatal exception

I tried adding following rules to proguard but with not luck (see below), any guesses what can it be?

```
# JSR 305 annotations are for embedding nullability information.
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**

# A resource is loaded with a relative path so the package of this class must be preserved.
-adaptresourcefilenames okhttp3/internal/publicsuffix/PublicSuffixDatabase.gz

# Animal Sniffer compileOnly dependency to ensure APIs are compatible with older versions of Java.
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.*

# OkHttp platform used only on JVM and when Conscrypt and other security providers are available.
-dontwarn okhttp3.internal.platform.**
-dontwarn org.conscrypt.**
-dontwarn org.bouncycastle.**
-dontwarn org.openjsse.**
```

**EDIT: error traced in mapping.txt, found out signalR was the problem, added following lines of code in proguard-rules.pro**

-keep class com.microsoft.signalr.** { *; }

-keep interface com.microsoft.signalr.** { *; }

Comment: You should consult the generated mapping.txt to see what `y4.c` class is.

Comment: Thanks for response! I already traced error in mapping.txt, and found out that the signalR was throwing error, so I went to a proguard-rules.pro and added following lines of code and afterwards, it worked.

-keep class com.microsoft.signalr.** { *; }
-keep interface com.microsoft.signalr.** { *; }

Hope this helps somebody

Comment: Good find! You should post that as an answer, not an edit. Questions with answers are more easily found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have traced error in mapping.txt, and found out that the SignalR was throwing error, so I went to a proguard-rules.pro and added following lines of code and afterwards, it worked.

```
-keep class com.microsoft.signalr.** { ; } 
-keep interface com.microsoft.signalr.* { *; }
```

Hope this helps